# match pattern css - not working

Tags: css

I have a requirement where I need to apply my custom colors to the ribbon styles instead of the default styles.

So, I have checked about pattern matching CSS and tried below, but it is not working.

My Actual CSS:

```
.ms-cui-cg-**tl** .ms-cui-ct-first>.ms-cui-tt-a,
.ms-cui-cg-**tl** .ms-cui-ct-first>.ms-cui-tt-a:hover {
  border-left-color: #000;
}

.ms-cui-cg-**gr** .ms-cui-ct-first>.ms-cui-tt-a,
.ms-cui-cg-**gr** .ms-cui-ct-first>.ms-cui-tt-a:hover {
  border-left-color: #000;
}
```

So to match this pattern, I have created some CSS like below.

```
div[class^="ms-cui-cg- .ms-cui-ct-first>.ms-cui-tt-a"],
div[class^="ms-cui-cg- .ms-cui-ct-first>.ms-cui-tt-a:hover"] {
  border-left-color: #000;
}
```

I'm trying to match the pattern with **tl** and **gr**
Can anyone correct the mistake I'm doing here?

Comment: This doesn't work because the `class=[...` selector works on the class attribute as a whole, not on the individual class names. In other words, your code is currently searching for a class attribute starting with this exact value: `class="ms-cui-cg- .ms-cui-ct-first>.ms-cui-tt-a:hover"` which you obviously don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
div[class^="ms-cui-cg-"] .ms-cui-ct-first>.ms-cui-tt-a,
div[class^="ms-cui-cg-"] .ms-cui-ct-first>.ms-cui-tt-a:hover {
  border-left-color: #000;
}
```

Same can be done for **gr** too